# counting number of customers per week during 6 years

Tags: python, pandas, join, group-by

I want to figure out number of customers per week during 6 years and add an extra column of number. this is what I tried:

```
df = df_eind[['year', 'week']].copy()
countv = df.groupby(['year', 'week']).year.count()
```

and then joined it with the main table which has the customer information like this:

```
df4 = df_eind.join(countv)
```

but gives an error because can not join a series with a data frame. can you please help me.

the data is like this(ex):

```
 year     week
 2012      2
 2018      50
 2015      16
 2012       2
```

and the file view should be like this(ex):

```
year  week  count
2012    2      2
2015   16      1
2018   50      1
```

Comment: Use `df_eind['count'] = df_eind.groupby(['year', 'week'])['year'].transform('size')`

Comment: @ jezrael, how about `df.groupby(['year', 'week'])['year'].count().values`

Comment: @jezrael I appreciate your help. It worked for me:)